# MongoDB and C# cheapest way to find Any in a collection

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm looking a linq equivalent to .Any for MongoDb's C# driver.
I have a collection of documents that have the property IsArchived. I just want to know if the collection contains any archived documents. For now, the least resource demanding method I have found is

`await Collection.CountDocumentsAsync(x => x.IsArchived) > 0`

I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this, as I assume this will still iterate and count all documents in the database collection. Is there a better way to do this or is that it?

Comment: How about limiting to a single result and checking to see if the cursor has an item or not? Be sure to have an index on the field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Any` (synchronous) or `AnyAsync` (asynchronous) method from the [`IMongoQueryable<T>`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_Linq_IMongoQueryable_1.htm).

> Determines whether the cursor returned by a cursor source contains any documents.

```cs
using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;

await Collection.AsQueryable()
    .AnyAsync(x => x.IsArchived);
```

Comment: This seems to take a little bit longer currently than the count method above. But it feels like the right way to do this. I'm assuming as my database gets larger, it will be faster than count.